# Windows Azure- Virtual machines ACL issue

Tags: iis, azure, virtual-machine, acl, azure-web-roles

I have created a VM in Windows Azure with following details:
  Location :South Central US 
  Image: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter.

I am trying to restrict users outside my organization network through setting IP range in endpoints.

What i have done so far:
1. Created a VM
2. Installed IIS on VM
3. Created an endpoint : Name- HTTP; Protocol-TCP;Public Port-80; Private Port-80
4. My system IP is 10.29.30.194 and subnet mask is  255.255.254.0, so as per this link [[http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=A]](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=A%5d) I find the range which comes as 10.29.30.0/23
5. Updated the ACl for HTTP endpoint as ACTION: Permit; REMOTE SUBNET: 10.29.30.0/23
6. Now when i trying access localhost in VM box it opens the default IIS page
7. When i try opening from my local system, VM IIS default page opens.
8. When i try opening the same HTTP link for IIS of VM from network other than the IP ranges provided, i can still access the VM IIS Default page. Which ideally should not be accessible as i gave permission only to my companies n/w IP's.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the ACL entry via the Management Portal or PowerShell?  If it's via PowerShell, remember that you need to 'commit' the change using the Update-AzureVM cmdlet.

Comment: I tried adding ACL entry via both Powershell and Management Portal, Also i committed the changes using the Update-AzureVM cmdlet but no success.